# Graphics cards not dispaying videos

Tags: graphics

I have 2 graphics cards and with either installed in the AGP slot they fail to display videos (youtube etc). The cards are a "Ati Sapphire Radeon 9250 256mb 128-bit ddr agp 4x/8x" and a "FX5200 256 MB". The former is using the distributed "radeon" driver and the latter using the proprietary nvidia driver. Which should I run with for optimum results and support within Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Install the device driver:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
```

Then reboot.

Comment: sadly this returns unable to locate package xserver-org-video-ati. I tried also with xserver.org-video-ati

Comment: It should be `xserver-xorg`. Not `xserver-org`.